# Error: Cannot invoke "jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute(String)" because "session" is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, httpsession

I have a Spring Boot application where I'm using HttpSession to store jwt tokens after login. In my AuthController, after successful login, I create a session and store the token in it. However, when I try to access the session in a subsequent request, specifically in the `/decode` endpoint, the session is null. (To display the logged user's name and email, I want to decode the token and get name and email from that.)

**AuthController Code:**

```
  @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> login(@RequestBody CredentialsDto credentialsDto, HttpServletRequest request) {
        UserDto userDto = userService.login(credentialsDto);

        if (userDto == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(null);
        }
        else {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("token", userAuthenticationProvider.createToken(userDto));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userDto);
        }
    }

@GetMapping("/decode")
    public ResponseEntity<?> decodeToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

            if(session != null)
            {
                UserDto userDto = userAuthenticationProvider.decodeToken((String)session.getAttribute("token"));
                return ResponseEntity.ok(userDto);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Session is null");
                return ResponseEntity.ok(null);
            }

        } catch (JWTDecodeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Error in decoding token");
        }
    }
```

What could be causing the session to be null in subsequent requests, and how can I resolve this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you storing a JWT in the session, its an antipattern.

Comment: Then where should I store it? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Its quite clear that you have not done proper research into how security works. JWTs are to be used between microservices in the backend and should not be handed out to browsers. You should read up on what session based authentication is, how cookies are used. What oauth2 is what open id connect is. If you are a beginner i suggest you read the architecture chapter of the spring security docs before asking on stack overflow as it is expected that tou at least read the basic docs.